# How do I refresh a specific controller in Angular.js (in app.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to refresh a specific controller in Angular.js, I can detect page changes like this:

```
//when app runs call this function.
app.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location, $cookies){
   //Bind the `$locationChangeSuccess` event on the rootScope, so that we dont need to 
   //bind in induvidual controllers.

   $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });        

   $rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
        if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
            console.log('user hit back');
            if($rootScope.actualLocation=='/'){
              //clear cookie
              var testing = $cookies.getObject('globals');
              $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I need to refresh my navigationController, so if the user presses the back button or refreshes their browser window it dynamically keeps its state.

Navigation controller:

nav.js

```
    'use strict';

    //app global variable
    //this is the controller that handles post requests
    //declare services as dependecies $http, $location, custom service apiServiceWeb
    app.controller('navigationController', function($scope, $route, $rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies, setCredentials) {

      //get what is in the cookie
      var cookieValue = setCredentials.getCookie('globals');
      console.log($cookies.get('globals'));

      //hide menu in certain paths 
      if ($location.path() == '/' || $location.path() == 'signup') {
        $scope.isConnected = true;

      } else {

        $rootScope.$watch('globals', function() {
          //if a currentUser does NOT exist, the hide menu.

          if (cookieValue = null) {
            $scope.isConnected = true;
          } else {

            $scope.isConnected = false;

          }

        });

      } 

    });

index.html
```

This is the view.

```
  <div ng-controller="navigationController">
          <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-hide="isConnected">
        <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
```

Comment: What is your navigation controller doing?  Shouldn't it idempotently be able to restore it's state every single page load?

Comment: amended the code by updating it, basically the problem is once the controller has been instantiated, the moment the user presses back or reloads their browser window by pressing "refresh" the controller loses its state.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to be able to restore the state on every single full page reload.  Nothing in javascript can maintain state on a page refresh.  If you wanted to store something persistently in between full refreshes, consider using session/local storage.

Comment: Stored the state inside cookie, the controller fetches data from the cookie the first time, but then doesnt get called again upon a page reload or back button pressed.

Comment: create  init() method in navCtrl and move all the code(not funtions) to it's inside. do a broadcast when you detect the change and inside the watch in navCtrl just call init()

Comment: sorry I am quite new to this, could you show me an example of this? Thanks codingNinja